# good Rails 3 WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg

I'm looking to add an editor to my app, similar to the one on Stackoverflow. I really just need some basic formatting (line spacing, bold, bullets etc.) and the ability to distinguish code (same style as SO).

Anyone know of any good solutions for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/), [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/) and [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) are possible options. StackOverflow itself uses WMD Editor, but it is hard to find an up-to-date repository for it. If you use Twitter's Bootstrap framework, then [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) is a good choice.

For TinyMCE there are suitable Ruby gems which facilitate the integration in Rails, namely [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) and [tinymce-rails-imageupload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload).

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), the former FCKeditor, is one of the most popular WYSIWYG editors.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Its Simple to use, what you have to do just add
    `<%= f.text_area :body, :rows => 20, :cols => 100, value:  @some_object.body ? @some_object.body : '' %>`

And use this inline script on that page itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'advanced',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,forecolor,backcolor,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect, link,unlink, image"
  });
</script>
```

As mention your just required only basic formatting so just changed theme_advanced_buttons.

Comment: An even simpler way to accomplish that with tinyMCE is to use the gem https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely urge you to try [Wysihat-Engine](https://github.com/80beans/wysihat-engine). It solved my problem of finding a simple wysiwyg editor for my app. Its seamless, even more if you're using paperclip. Its a wrapper around the 'WYSIHAT' written by 37signals.

Comment: It's good but, this editor has many issues, also very hard to customize.

Comment: FYI, 37signals' Wysihat depends on Prototype (!) for it's magic. Unless your using Prototype (!), this isn't the Wysiwyg editor you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any generic javascript WYSIWYG library. Here's [WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/demo), it supports Markdown which you can render from your Rails app using [Bluecloth 2](https://github.com/ged/bluecloth).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ruby on rails plugin: https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce it's realy powerfull and easy to implement.
Checkout the editor on http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/